# How can I listen to a playlist on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad

I see my iTunes playlists (from my computer) in Remote but when I play one of them the sound comes from my computer but not from the iPad. How can I hear the sound on my iPad? Thank you.                                            iPad Pro Wi-Fi, iOS 10.3.1

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered, the Remote app can really only be used to remotely control playback on other devices.

If you don't wish to sync the playlists from your computer to your iPad via iTunes, then you'll have to stream them some other way. Unfortunately, for whatever (probably music industry-enforced) reason, Apple's own AirPlay technology does not allow sending audio from a Mac or Windows PC to an iOS device. Fortunately, there are 3rd-party solutions that do allow this, like [AirFoil](https://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/).

Comment: Thank you. I have subscribed to Apple Music (trial). It seems that once my iTunes library from my MacBook is uploaded to the iCloud  Music Library I should be able to play songs in a playlist. I will also look into Airfoil. Now I only need to figure out what iTunes Match is!!